# Training frequency in relation to recovery and soreness

Tags: workout, recovery, muscle-soreness, exercise-frequency

Currently I am training on a 3-day full body workout split. It alternates between two workouts (A/B) with different focus, though every major muscle group is still trained in every workout. I train Mon/Wed/Fri, always in the evenings, so I get almost exactly 48h (or 72h over the weekend) of recovery.

I keep the weekly volume per body part to about 10-15 sets of 6-12 reps, depending on the exercise/muscle group (see [this article](https://legionathletics.com/full-body-workout-routine/#1-fullbody-workouts-may-make-it-easier-to-do-highquality-volume), which talks about required volume). That makes about 3-5 sets per muscle group per workout, consisting of mostly free weight compound exercices.

I noticed that on chest exercises, I seem to make very little progress, stall or even regress at times, meaning I have a very hard time adding weight/reps and sometimes can't even hit the same numbers as in the last workout. For chest specifically, I do 3x8-12 DB Bench Press + 2x10-15 Incline Push-Ups in workout A, and 4x8-12 Incline Bench Press in workout B. For the first 2 (workout A) respectively 3 (workout B) sets, I keep the RPE at about an 8, for the last set I go for an RPE of 9-10. Since the overall volume per workout isn't high, I went for more intensity, this didn't seem like too much to me. Overall, I don't feel weak and am seeing progress, so overtraining my whole body is definitely not the problem, especially with only 3 days.

Now I have three actual questions:

- Could my chest need more recovery and the weak progress/stalling is due to too much frequency for this muscle group? Or is that definitely not an option with that amount of volume and I just need to push through it?
- Generally, is it wise to push hard on full body 3 times a week or do I need better strategies to balance intensity and recovery, e.g. light/low effort and heavy/high effort days?
- The mountain dog talked about recovery and soreness in [this video](https://mountaindogdiet.com/basic/basic-training/5-tips-to-gain-muscle-mass-as-a-natural/), saying that sore = not fully recovered. Is this a fact and should sore muscles not be trained with weights at all? Are there degrees to this, so maybe working out with only slight soreness is okay?

Comment: "RPE of about 8-10. This doesn't seem like too much to me." I struggle to understand how these can both be true. An RPE 10 is an epic event involving maximal full-body effort. Four sets a workout at or near that intensity should feel like a lot.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. I guess I did not describe that correctly: On all the sets but the last one, I keep it at about an 8, and go for 9 or 10 on the last. So I have three sets @ RPE ~8 and one set @ RPE 9-10. Do you still think I should keep it lower and only occasionally push that close (or all the way) to failure? 
I also edited the question to be more clear on that.

Comment: There are many reasons the chest could be lagging. Re: working out while sore; it really depends. Personally I think active recovery is better than inactive, so reducing volume/weight/etc. would be preferred to doing nothing, but it depends on what kind of soreness we're talking about. 3x/wk seems a bit much, e.g., I think 2x/wk if you're seeing soreness from a relatively low per-workout volume might be worth trying.

Comment: Allright, thanks for the reply. The soreness is never so severe that I couldn't do anything, so active recovery instead of heavy weights seems reasonable. 2x/week is definitely worth a shot,  I'll adjust my workouts accordingly and see how it goes.